# How to add data sheet to a SharePoint web page?

Tags: publishing-site, datasheet

I am using SharePoint 2007 + Windows Server 2008 with SharePoint 2007's publishing portal template. I want to add Excel style data sheet to a web page, could anyone show me how?

More details,

1. For normal user (e.g. anonymous user), he/she could view and sort by column;
2. For administrator, he/she could edit cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is in a SharePoint List, you could just create a view on the List that is specifically of type DataSheet with the appropriate columns, go through the steps of adding a Web Part to your page (Site Actions-->Edit Page...) picking your SharePoint List which will use the default view initially, then choose Modify the Web Part from its dropdown menu and at the top of the new menu on the right side of the site choose your new DataSheet view you created.

Your users will now have all the functionality of the DataSheet view without having to go into the List and then picking the view.  You'll have to watch out for real estate issues, especially if you have a lot of columns for users to view/edit.  In that case you might want to use SP Desiner to add a new tablerow in the body that is colspan=2 to be the width of the left Web Part Zone AND the right Web Part Zone.

Hope that helps.

Comment: When I create the data sheet view, there is an error message like this, When I create a custom list, I met with the following error message, any ideas what is wrong?

An error occurred during the processing of . Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder' does not have a public property named 'width'. 
Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services.

Comment: That's a strange error to occur, almost as if part of the .NET 2 SharePoint Library's aren't fully loading.  Are you running WSS 3 or MOSS 2007?  Does this also occur on the canned Lists as well?  If not, you might take one of the canned List's and modify the columns until that bug is tracked down.

Comment: 1. I am running MOSS 2007 x64 Standard Edition (with trial license) on Windows Server 2008 x64, is this version capable of creating list as you mentioned above? 2. What do you mean "canned" Lists? canned means? Could you say in some other words please? Sorry English is not my native language.

Comment: Guess what - the ContentPlaceHolder does indeed not have a property named width, so the error message makes sense and might even be accurate! ContentPlaceHolders generally reside in the master page, so my guess it that you customized the master and accidentally added a "width" attribute to one of the ContentPlaceHolders.

Comment: Thanks Jaap, you are correct and I customized master page related to width property. I have a new idea to verify -- here is my idea, create a publishing portal in a clean machine (in this scenario, master page should be using the default one, no change), and I will follow your advice in this clean environment to create datasheet list, and if success, it could prove it is my master page customization issue, correct?

Comment: "the ContentPlaceHolder does indeed not have a property named width" -- do you mean ContentPlaceHolder have a width property or not actually?

Comment: Cool, pilkentonc! Question answered!

Comment: George, the ContentPlaceHolder class does not have a width property, so you cannot set it. If you try to add width="100%" or something like that on the <asp:ContentPlaceHolder> tag, you should get an error message similar to what you posted in one of your earlier comments.