# Add a list to a publishing page with quick edit enabled

Tags: list-view, publishing-page

I am using SharePoint 2013

I cannot seem to find any information on this at all so here goes.
I have a list that i have created a datasheet view on. I go to a web part page i have created an add this list to the page and point it to my datasheet view.

The view is displayed but not in datasheet mode and the "Quick Edit" button on the ribbon is greyed out.

I really need the quick edit feature as uses will come to this page to basically tick off items so they don't want to have to open each item individually.

I know I could link users directly to the list but I want to add other things to page to help guide users.

Am I trying to do something that isn't supported or is my approach just wrong?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/456/how-to-add-data-sheet-to-a-sharepoint-web-page

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are adding the view to the page from the Designer - 
Check if the DataSheet view is your default view

The default view gets picked up from the designer when adding

Answer (score 0):

go into the webpart properties, change the view to the view you made (datasheet view). The webpart should now reflect that view! also change the toolbar type to full toolbar!

make sure the group or users have the correct permissions to the list!